# Joining two query result's column side by side in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I've write two query from same table but I need the result side by side, I've tried but getting error

First Query--

```
select trunc(CONFIRM_DATE) RE_REG_DATE, to_char(CONFIRM_DATE,'HH24') as "ret_req_Hour", count(*) as Total_H_Hour
from MYTABLE
where trunc(CONFIRM_DATE) between'26-MAR-2016' and '26-MAR-2016'
and TO_char(CONFIRM_DATE,'HH24') in ('10','11','12','13','16','17','18','19')
group by trunc(CONFIRM_DATE), to_char(CONFIRM_DATE,'HH24')
```

Second Query

```
select to_char(CONFIRM_DATE,'HH24') as "ret_req_Hour", count(*) as Hourly_S
from MYTABLE
where trunc(CONFIRM_DATE) between'26-MAR-2016' and '26-MAR-2016'
and TO_char(CONFIRM_DATE,'HH24') in ('10','11','12','13','16','17','18','19')
and status in ('C','Y','E')
group by trunc(CONFIRM_DATE), to_char(CONFIRM_DATE,'HH24')
order by trunc(CONFIRM_DATE),to_char(CONFIRM_DATE,'HH24');
```

Comment: Just curious - why "between '26-MAR-2016' and '26-MAR-2016'" and not simply  "= '26-MAR-2016'"? Also, why "in ('10', ... , '19')" and not simply "between '10' and '19'"? It would also help to extract the hour as a number; unfortunately, the EXTRACT function in Oracle doesn't work on dates, only on timestamps, so you have to do it indirectly, for example:  TRUNC ((CONFIRM_DATE - TRUNC(CONFIRM_DATE))*24).

Comment: Its a just sample query I posted, I had to also check within date range.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select trunc(CONFIRM_DATE) as RE_REG_DATE,
       to_char(CONFIRM_DATE, 'HH24') as ret_req_Hour,
       count(*) as Total_H_Hour,
       sum(case when status in ('C', 'Y', 'E') then 1 else 0 end) as Hourly_S
from MYTABLE
where trunc(CONFIRM_DATE) between '26-MAR-2016' and '26-MAR-2016' and
      TO_char(CONFIRM_DATE, 'HH24') in ('10', '11', '12', '13', '16', '17', '18', '19')
group by trunc(CONFIRM_DATE), to_char(CONFIRM_DATE,'HH24')
```